# Is it possible to forge HttpRequest attributes for a Django server

Tags: python, django, http, authentication

I am writing a web app using Django. I am trying to allow a user to see its profile and only his own.

```
if(not request.user.id == request.GET.get('user_id', '')):
    raise PermissionDenied
```

My question is: is it safe to check this way or is it possible for a smart kid to somehow alter the value in `request.user.id` to match the `user_id` of anyone?

The user must be logged in before accessing this page using this:

```
user = LDAPBackend().authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if(user is not None):
    login(request, user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be safe.

request.user get's only populated when authentication with session cookies. Unless and until someone steals the cookie or token it should be no issue.

One thing i don't understand is why do you need `user_id` parameter here to be explicitly passed.

if you are putting logged in compulsory to view the page. there are two way i can see this.

1. `/profile`

Directly get user profile corresponding to the `request.user`

2. `/<username>`

Query the profile corresponding to the username and compare it with request.user.id

Comment: This is a grading app, so any Teacher can access any Student profile, but any Student can only see its own profile. That's why I explicitly pass the student_id. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is set using [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) for each request:

> Adds the `user` attribute, representing the currently-logged-in user, to every incoming `HttpRequest` object.

If a user is not logged in then `request.user` is set to Anonymous User. Have a look at [Authentication in Web requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests).

So, I am not sure how would a smart kid alter the id of the logged-in user.

Mostly, there is a `one-to-one` relation between the `user` and its profile. If that's the case you can modify the queryset to get the profile for `request.user` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is already an object about the current user who send the request to get the page. You can use `login_required` or  to only allow user login to access ([2 solutions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) : decorator or Mixin).

And then you can use your condition to load the page in the function. Example:

=> url.py:

```
url(r'^profile/$', login_required(app.views.profile), name='profile'),
```

=> views.py :

```
def profile(request):
try:
    myProfile = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return render(request, "error.html", {'message' : 'No Profile Found'})
return render(request, "app/profile.html",
              {'myProfile': myProfile})
```

Like this you can only display YOUR profile (user who send the request) AND you need to be logged.

EDIT: if you don't want "try and catch" you can use `get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)`